# is OAPageBean Class is act as a Controller?

Tags: oaf

> Hi Every One.Now i started to learn OAF.I read some articles related
>   to OAF.In this articles they mention when user first sent a request
>   for OA.jsp page then  that request received by OAPageBean class.As per
>   my knowledge if OAF follow MVC architecture then that request received
>   by Controller.So any one please clarify me whether OAPageBean is a
>   controller or bean and how it work when browser sent a request for jsp
>   page?

Answer (score 0):

OAPageBean is not a controller. It is the main OA Framework page processing class.

- The OAPageBean calls the processRequest method when a browser issues a GET request.
- The OAPageBean then calls processFormData for pages that insert or update data.
- The OAPageBean calls the processFormRequest method when a browser issues a POST request.